# Partial message problem using java nio

Tags: java, sockets, nio

My sending messages may be larger than the default socket buffer size. So there may be several read operations in order to receive a complete message. When the end condition is

```
n = socket.read(rbuf);  
if(n==0) || (n==-1) 
   break;
```

The exception of partial message still exists. Is any good way to solve this problem. Thanks

I use multiple processes running on one machine. Each process uses a nio socket. Is this a possible factor to cause the partial messages?

Answer (score 3):

0 is a valid return value for read, which does not indicate the end of the channel. -1 indicates the end of the channel. So if you end the reading when 0 is returned, you'll get partial messages.

Comment: I solve the problem by first buffer the message to be complete. The complete condition is the end characters are met.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) which is built on top of Java's NIO classes but gives you a (in my opinion) much more usable API than the Java JDK NIO classes.

To solve your problem you would use a [ReplayingDecoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/replay/ReplayingDecoder.html) and Netty will simply call your stream (ChannelBuffer) decoder again and again until you've got enough data to make sense of it.

Comment: How hard to transfer from Java JDK NIO classes to Netty? Is there any example?

Comment: It really depends on how much NIO code you've got.  Netty is MUCH easier than Java's NIO (IMHO) so using it is quicker (i find).  However, obviously if you have a massive amount of Java NIO code this may be impractical in the short term.  Perhaps implement a new feature in Netty alongside your existing code and see if it works for you.